# ImageIO saves back to original size

Tags: java, graphics, awt, graphics2d, javax.imageio

I've been searching for some solutions from the internet yet I still haven't found an answer to my problem.

I've been working or doing a program that would get an image file from my PC then will be edited using `Java Graphics` to add some text/object/etc. After that, `Java ImageIO` will save the newly modified image.

So far, I was able to do it nicely but I got a problem about the size of the image. The original image and the modified image didn't have the same size.

The original is a `2x3`inches-image while the modified one which supposedly have 2x3inches too sadly got `8x14`inches. So, it has gone BIGGER than the original one.

What is the solution/code that would give me an output of 2x3inches-image which will still have a 'nice quality'?

**UPDATE:**

So, here's the code I used.

```
public Picture(String filename) {
    try {
        File file = new File("originalpic.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        width  = image.getWidth();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not open file: " + filename);
    }
}

private void write(int id) {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("newpic.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**2nd UPDATE:**

I now know what's the problem of the new image. As I check it from Photoshop, It has a different image resolution compared to the original one. The original has a 300 pixels/inch while the new image has a 72 pixels/inch resolution.

How will I be able to change the resolution using Java?

Comment: The question is a bit general, but my guess is that you are saving in a format with a different DPI setting.   Post some code and we can try to help.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your problem.

Comment: Strange. Every transformation on the Graphics2D should be mirrored with an inverse transformation. _I do not know, but that seems the only explanation._ Clipping needed?

Comment: I edited your question to add a ..question.  If that is **not** the question, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17616528/edit) accordingly with your own.

Comment: I updated my post above and added the code I used.

Answer (score 4):

To set the image resolution (of the JFIF segment), you can probably use the `IIOMetatada` for JPEG.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class MetadataTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
        writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("foo.jpg")));
        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

        IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(image), param);
        IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());
        IIOMetadataNode jfif = (IIOMetadataNode) root.getElementsByTagName("app0JFIF").item(0);

        jfif.setAttribute("resUnits", "1");
        jfif.setAttribute("Xdensity", "300");
        jfif.setAttribute("Ydensity", "300");

        metadata.mergeTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName(), root);

        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), param);
    }
}
```

**Note: this code should not be used verbatim, but adding iteration, error handling, stream closing etc, clutters the example too much.**

See [JPEG Image Metadata DTD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html) for documentation on the metadata format, and what options you can control.