# Increase PPI on BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, ppi

Is it possible to control the PPI (I want to increase it) on a BufferedImage? I use ImageIO.write to write the BufferedImage to a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly. A `BufferedImage` consists of only pixel data (raster), a sample model and a color model. It has no knowledge of PPI/DPI.

But if the format you are writing supports setting PPI/DPI, you can typically control this by passing the proper `IIOMetadata` along with the image to the `ImageWriter` when writing.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616528/imageio-saves-back-to-original-size/17649916#17649916) for how to do this for JPEG.