# What class(es) are used for bitmap conversion & metadata in Java 1.6?

Tags: java, image, bitmap, metafile

We have some old code (Java 1.2) that heavily uses JAI_IO for image manipulation. We're now Java 1.6 and so we no longer need this. First off, should I still be using BufferedImage? Or is there a better class? What I fundamentally need to do is:

1. Convert a bitmap from one format to another (usually to PNG).
2. Get the metadata of an image: size in pixels, DPI, & bitmap format.
3. Resize an image.
4. Draw an image to a Graphics2D object.
5. walk the pixels in a bitmap to read and/or set them (this can be slow - rarely used).

And I know the answer is "ha ha ha" but is there a class that will convert metafiles to a bitmap?

thanks - dave

Comment: What would make a class "better" than `BufferedImage`? What issues do you have with the existing setup? For Java 6, I would probably use the standard `javax.imageio` API. Optionally use the JAI ImageIO plugins, if you need support for the formats it contains.

Comment: @haraldK - What we need that BufferedImage does not appear to have are: 1) convert a bitmap to another format, 2) DPI settings for a bitmap, 3) Get format of bitmap.

Comment: The `javax.imageio` API is good for those tasks. `BufferedImage` just represents pixel data. There's a class `IIOImage` that contains metadata (`IIOMetadata`), like file format details and DPI, along with the pixel data (in the form of a `BufferedImage`, or its superclass `RenderedImage`).

Comment: @haraldK - how can we use IIOImage to get the DPI and bitmap format? thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `ImageIO` and the `javax.imageio` API to read the image and adjust DPI/PPI (see below for an example), and probably a package like [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) or [thumbnailator](https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) to resize, depending on your needs/preferences.

The code goes something like:

```
// input is typically a File or InputStream

// Wrap in ImageInputStream
ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);

// Obtain reader
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next(); // In real code, test for presence
reader.setInput(stream);

String formatName = reader.getFormatName(); // Get the format name

ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

// ... modify params as you see fit, or just go with defaults

IIOImage image = reader.readAll(0, param);

RenderedImage red = image.getRenderedImage();
BufferedImage buf = (BufferedImage) red; // In real code, test if it's safe, or convert

// .. pas buf along to imgscalr or thumnailator

image.setRenderedImage(buf);

IIOMetadata meta = image.getMetadata();

// ... modify DPI in meta data

ImageWriter writer = reader.getImageWriter();
writer.write(null, image, null); // Or modify write params if you need (last parameter)
```

You can see an example of [modifying the DPI for JPEG files here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649916/1428606).