# Change X & Y Density and Color Depth of JPEG Image

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg, dpi

I want to change jpeg image density from 96 to 100 dpi and bit depth should be 8 bit.

I'm using below code.

```
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    JPEGImageEncoder jpegEncoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(os1);
    JPEGEncodeParam jpegEncodeParam = jpegEncoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bufferedImage);
    jpegEncodeParam.setDensityUnit(JPEGEncodeParam.DENSITY_UNIT_DOTS_INCH);
    jpegEncoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(jpegEncodeParam); 
    jpegEncodeParam.setQuality(0.40f, true);
    jpegEncodeParam.setXDensity(100); 
    jpegEncodeParam.setYDensity(100);
    jpegEncoder.encode(bufferedImage, jpegEncodeParam);
    bufferedImage.flush();
```

It's working fine but in this code Java API showing warning message that is `Access restriction: The type 'JPEGImageEncoder' is not API (restriction on required library ...).` and Maven build also by this.

Also tried ImageIO library but It only helps in bit depth and not able to change dpi.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649916/1428606) for how to set DPI in JPEG using ImageIO.

Comment: When you say *"bit depth should be 8"*, do you mean the output should be 8 bits per channel (24 bit for RGB/8 bit for gray) or something else?

Comment: @haraldK it means 8 bit for gray